# helm rabbitmq ha keep volume outside minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the rabbitmq helm chart from here: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha

and I want to store the messages and queues outside minikube so I can continue from there everytime I run minikube. However, I cannot see in the documentation how to add a volume or persistent volume to point to my host machine.

Comment: Are you asking, how to use persistent volume with rabbitmq chart or how to map persistent volume to your local directory?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I don't have anything outside minikube in my host machine so no mapping. I want to continue with the data that my rabbitmq generates even if I stop minikube

Comment: You need to map `hostPath` from minikube's VM to your host. You can access minikube VM with `minikube ssh`. Then, read in your VM docs, how you can map directory from VM to host.

Comment: ok I'll look at the vm docs @GrigoriyMikhalkin however, where's the data from rabbitmq stored inside minikube? can you post it as an answer so I can validate it?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/) is minikube docs for `PersistentVolume`. It supports `hostPath` out of the box, so you can just set it's path to any existing directory in your VM(i'm assume you using some VM as a driver). Then, if rabbitmq, persists any data in `PersistentVolume`, you cn retrieve it from there.

To get this data on your host, you will need to map VM directory(which you're using for `hostPath`) to host directory. You can access VM with `minikube ssh` command. Then read VM docs on how you cn map directory to host directory.

Comment: the link suggests that the data is safely stored inside /tmp/hostpath-provisioner/<nameofPV> which is true because I ssh into minikube and the folders are there. However, when I restart minikube rabbitmq has no queues that should have been saved. Why is that?

Comment: @alex  Seems like, official docs lying a little bit) https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5706 -- FWIU, `minikube stop`, currently, doesn't suspends a VM.

Comment: I added my answer thanks to your suggestions which helped me to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to Grigoriy Mikhalkin. My problem was that I was using **hyperkit** that deleted the data when I run `minikube stop`  whereas if we use **virtualbox** as the driver and run minikube stop  the data will be there next time we run `minikube start`

```js
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

Comment: It's important to mention that some drivers will mount a host folder within the VM so that you can easily share files between the VM and host. You can use this to save files outside your minikube cluster so they will always be available for you. Check the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#mounted-host-folders) to know more about it.